# vuejs, how to use v-bind to bind class within a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

The table looks like:

| platform | description | remark | button |

When I click a **Forward** button, which set this row's `clicked=true`, why the button's class is still `btn-primary`(color: blue)  instead of `btn-danger`(color: red)?

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            grid_data: [], //ajax
        },
        methods: {
            "forward": function (url, index) {
                this.grid_data[index].clicked = true;
                openWindow(url);
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
    <tr v-for="(item,index) in grid_data">
        <td>{{ item.platform }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.remark }}</td>
        <td>
            <button v-bind:class="[item.clicked ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary', 'btn', 'btn-sm' ]" v-on:click="forward(item.url, index)">Forward</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Repproducing it on jsFddle works (https://jsfiddle.net/r_vamsi_krishna/dsezdx8f/3/). What does `openWindow(url);` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is likely that the `clicked` attribute does not exist on your data until you add it via your method, and Vue [cannot detect that you added it](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Change your code to use [$set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

```
methods: {
  "forward": function (url, index) {
    this.$set(this.grid_data[index], 'clicked',true);
    openWindow(url);
  }
},
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/JJbzeL?editors=1010).

Additionally, you can avoid passing indexes around. Just pass the item itself.

```
v-on:click="forward(item)
```

And in your method,

```
"forward": function (item) {
  this.$set(item, 'clicked',true);
  openWindow(item.url);
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(() => this.grid_data = gridData, 500)` solved using setTimeout. (data load using ajax -> new Vue({}) -> setTimeout)

Comment: @wtf512 I only used `setTimeout` to simulate populating the data using an ajax call.